# crispy-forms error message in select field

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

I have a select field in my crispy form. How can I make the cross to not be layered over with the select button itself?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to just remove the cross completely by setting

```
.form-control.is-invalid
{
background-image: none
}
```

in CSS file.